# Rspec not recognizing tables in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec, sinatra

I am creating a lightweight app that requires custom routes so I'm using Sinatra over Rails. However, I am using a skeleton that closely mimics Rails functionality, just without having to fight convention at every turn.

The problem is that when I try and run Rspec, it tells me that there is no relation. I keep thinking there must be a pluralization issue, but for the light of me, I can't find it. I'm not trying to do anything fancy (yet), but just be able to make something so I can start putting in validations and such after.

Code Examples:

THE PROBLEM

When I run bundle exec rspec:

```
  1) Admin successfully creates Admin
 Failure/Error: admin = Admin.new
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "admins" does not exist
   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                                             ^
   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  ORDER BY a.attnum
 # ./spec/admin_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But run manually in the console:

```
irb(main):007:0> Admin.all.length
D, [2016-05-04T18:42:02.818958 #30608] DEBUG -- :   Admin Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins"
=> 0
irb(main):008:0> admin = Admin.new
=> #<Admin id: nil, name: nil, password: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):009:0> admin.save
D, [2016-05-04T18:42:15.127732 #30608] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-05-04T18:42:15.140416 #30608] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "admins" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2016-05-05 01:42:15.130599"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-05 01:42:15.130599"]]
D, [2016-05-04T18:42:15.146401 #30608] DEBUG -- :    (2.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):010:0> Admin.all.length
D, [2016-05-04T18:42:28.236480 #30608] DEBUG -- :   Admin Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins"
=> 1
```

THE CODE

The Model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Remember to create a migration!
end
```

The Migration:

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin do

  it "successfully creates Admin" do
    admin = Admin.new
    expect(admin.save).to change{Admin.all.length}.by(1)
  end

end
```

spec helper:

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'shoulda-matchers'
require 'rack/test'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

Capybara.app = app.new
```

I hope this is enough information, This is my first question, tell me if you need more, or if less would have been better. Thank you!

Also I've seen solutions to this involving rake tasks specific to Rails. Most of these don't exist in Sinatra and I'm having trouble finding the source code to get it into my Sinatra app.

Comment: I see:

    WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'

Are the double quotes supposed to be part of the string?  I would think not, but I may be wrong.  I would think it should be:

    WHERE a.attrelid = 'admins'

Comment: @KeithBennett I agree, since it has two sets of quotes. My problem is I have no idea WHY it's doing that. I've seen it before, but it always meant I forgot to migrate or mispluralized. :(

Answer (score 1):

rake db:migrate RACK_ENV=test

I'm not going to lie, I tried this like six times. but it finally worked so for the next poor soul going down the rabbit hole ...

Answer (score 0):

That's because rspec runs in test environment. It seems your app have no test database.

I had the same issue in the first run of your code

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp/sinatra-activerecord-starter-kit]$ git:(master) be rspec
.F

Failures:

1) Admin successfully creates Admin
 Failure/Error: admin = Admin.new

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "admins" does not exist
   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                                             ^
   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  ORDER BY a.attnum

Finished in 0.09315 seconds (files took 1.28 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure
```

Then I created test database

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp/sinatra-activerecord-starter-kit]$ git:(master) ENV=test rake db:setup
sinatra_development already exists
sinatra_test already exists
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0100s
-- create_table("admins", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0109s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0016s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0104s
-- create_table("admins", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0186s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0046s
```

And changed your test a little: you should use a block in `expect {}.to change`, not just prenthesis.
Because it will fail with

```
  1) Admin successfully creates Admin
     Failure/Error: expect(admin.save).to change{Admin.all.length}.by(1)
       expected result to have changed by 1, but was not given a block
     # ./spec/models/admin_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So just replace parenthesis with a block

```
describe Admin do

  it "successfully creates Admin" do
    admin = Admin.new
    expect { admin.save }.to change{Admin.all.length}.by(1)
  end

end
```

and test wil pass

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp/sinatra-activerecord-starter-kit]$ git:(master) be rspec
D, [2016-05-05T08:52:22.200133 #16356] DEBUG -- :   Admin Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins"
.

Finished in 0.03326 seconds (files took 0.77676 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: I changed the test, and tried your other suggestions. The environment was being set in a helper, so I edited above to include that. The rake tasks for db trigger both environments (development and test) so that is there. However, I did try manually testing (ENV as above and RACK_ENV as in the helper) and it still gives the same error. Thank you for your advice re: rspec however. I must have misread my previous tests when I glanced at them to be sure I remembered.

Comment: Could you please provide output of `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ENV['RACK_ENV']`
?
Ofc when running in test environment.

Comment: Also, please provide your `spec_helper.rb`